# Problems with rendering page on Django framework

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have categories of the news and news and i don't know how to render the page with the list of news that belong to the same category. Hope You will help me with that.
this is my model.py file:

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
        class Meta:
                verbose_name_plural = u'Categories'

        category = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        slug = models.CharField(max_length=255)

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.category

class News(models.Model):

        class Meta:
                verbose_name_plural = u'News'

        title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        category = models.ForeignKey(u'Category', related_name=u'Category', blank=True, null=True)
        pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
        slug = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        short_content=models.TextField(max_length=2000, blank=True)
        content = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
        image = models.FileField(u'Images', upload_to='media/img/news', blank=True)


        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.title
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from news.models import News

class NewsListView(ListView):
        template_name ='news/list.html'
        context_object_name = 'news_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
            return News.objects.order_by('-pub_date') [:5]


class  NewsDetailView(DetailView):
    model=News
    template_name = 'news/detail.html'

def CategoryNews(request, categoryslug):
    category = Category.objects.get(slug=categoryslug)
    news = News.objects.filter(category=category)
    return render (request, 'news/category_news.html', {'category' : category})
```

urls.py:

```
django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from news.views import NewsListView, NewsDetailView
from news import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', NewsListView.as_view(), name='list'),
        url(r'^(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/$', NewsDetailView.as_view()),
        url(r'^kids-garden/$', views.CategoryNews),
)
```

Thank You!

Comment: The Django tutorial actually covers this exact situation.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/ https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On CategoryNews view add news to render context. This will make news items available in templates.

```
def CategoryNews(request, categoryslug):
    category = Category.objects.get(slug=categoryslug)
    news = News.objects.filter(category=category)
    return render (request, 'news/category_news.html', {'category' : category, 'newsitems': news})
```

Add named group to category url to make it dynamic.

Rewrite

```
url(r'^kids-garden/$', views.CategoryNews, name='category'),
```

to

```
url(r'^category/(?P<categoryslug>\w+)/$', views.CategoryNews, name='category'),
```

In category_news.html

```
{%for news in newsitems%}

    {{ news.title }}
    {{ news.content }}
    # rest values...........
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank You @moonstruck. I did same as you wrote, but when I try to access to the adress ..//news/<categoryslug>/ (in my case is /news/kids-garden/), I got the error "Page not found (404), No news found matching the query ". But I have 3 news in this category.

Comment: Try this `news = News.objects.filter(category__slug='categoryslug')`

Comment: I change the places NewsDetailView with CategoryNews in urls.py file. And CategoryNews start work! But NewsDetailView stop to work. It raise the error "Category matching query does not exist"

Comment: It's because both url pattern is almost same. Better change category url to something like this. `url(r'^category/(?P<categoryslug>\w+)/$', views.CategoryNews, name='category'),` and update links on template if there's any.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the job:

views.py

```
....
from news.models import News, Category

def CategoryNews(request, categoryslug):
    category_news = News.objects.filter(category__slug='categoryslug')
    return render (request, 'news/category_news.html', {'category_news' : category_news})
```